# HTML Imports not working

Tags: html, import

I am trying to use HTML import for the header & footer on my site as I will be updating these frequently and want to avoid manually updating every page individually.

Here is the import code, which is contained within the  tags in my index.html file:

```
<link rel="import" href="/includes/header.html">
```

This does not work (nothing changes) and likewise for the footer.

Here is the contents of the header.html file:

```
<nav style="background: none;width:100%;border:none" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="/logos/logo.png" style="width:150px; display:inline;">
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
                    </ul>-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="float:right;display:inline;position:relative;">
      <li><a href="/mission" style="color:white;">Our Mission</a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Browser support for html import is pretty limited, are you working in one of the green ones? http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Comment: The W3C doesn't mention `rel="import"` on their website, so I think the problem is simply that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

HTML `Import` only work natively in Chrome. Google Chrome has had support since version 31, but you still need to enable the feature manually. For more details Click [enter link description here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports)

Not supported in Firefox.

So, I suggest you can use `PHP` function `include` and `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<link rel="import" href="./includes/header.html">
```

the "." says look in the folder in the path

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<?php include "/includes/header.html"; ?>`
or add your [link tag inside head tag](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) if it's not.